# No wifi connection for Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150

Tags: wireless, windows-7, connection, intel-wireless

I am a new Ubuntu user; I recently switched over from Windows (pats self on back).  However, I can't seem to figure out how to get my wireless connection to work.  The only way for my connection to work at the moment is by Ethernet cable.  Basically, I can detect all of the connection sites in my area, but once I select the one I want and I type in the password, it thinks for a moment possibly trying to get me connected then it brings me back to the password window.  I've ensured I'm using the correct password, and I don't know what to do at this point.  Any direction you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

My network controller is: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

How odd.  It sees the wireless device, and even its connections, but won't connect.  I've heard that a lot lately, but so far only about version 14.04 and 14.10.  Maybe I should just be glad I'm still using 12.04?

I suppose it could be that the default driver your wifi device is using isn't quite right.

Generally speaking, if you are connected to the internet using a wired connection and perform and update, drivers for such hardware will automatically be installed.  Not always but mostly.  It is always my first thing I try.

Have you tried clicking on additional drivers under system settings?

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the newer Intel Wifi Cards: it currently does not have native support--as far as I can tell. What you need is the right firmware. I have found the firmware for [Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) as well as brief instructions on the installation of firmware.

Download the corresponding firmware tarball. (iwlwifi-6050-ucode-9.201.4.1.tgz)
[Unpack the tarball, change into it's uncompressed directory, and move the iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode file to the firmware directory, /lib/firmware.](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/loading-firmware.html)

```
user@bash-X900V:pwd$ tar -xvzf iwlwifi-6050-ucode*
iwlwifi-6050-ucode-9.201.4.1/
iwlwifi-6050-ucode-9.201.4.1/LICENSE.iwlwifi-6050-ucode
iwlwifi-6050-ucode-9.201.4.1/README.iwlwifi-6050-ucode
iwlwifi-6050-ucode-9.201.4.1/iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode

user@bash-X900V:pwd$ cd iwlwifi-6050-ucode-9.201.4.1/
user@bash-X900V:pwd/iwlwifi-6050-ucode-9.201.4.1$ sudo mv iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode /lib/firmware/
user@bash-X900V:pwd/iwlwifi-6050-ucode-9.201.4.1$ sudo reboot
```

Reboot and pray.

Answer (score 0):

Even I did face the same issue. The Ubuntu default network manager has some issues. I switched to new Network Manager WICD which solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```